# Как задать символ или конец строки в регулярном выражении?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

На вход подаются строки вида

> `asdfsadfs=dfasfsdfd; sdfasdf
> dfsdff=sdfsdf;
> dsfasdfsdf=sdfsdf`

Как извлечь то, что начинается знаками "=" и ";" либо "=" и концом строки (то есть от первого вхождения знака "=" до первого вхождения знака ";" либо до конца строки если нет знака ";")?

```
string x = Regex.Match(z, @"\=(.*?)[;$]").Groups[1].Value;
```

Знак "$" внутри символьного класса не воспринимается как конец строки.

Comment: Могу предложить `=(.*?)(;|$)`, но это не оптимальное решение.

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Answer (score 4):

Решение найдено. Если первый ограничитель есть всегда, а последний может как быть, так и не быть, то надо включить второй ограничитель в символьный класс как исключаемый символ.

```
string x = Regex.Match(z, @"\=([^\=\;]+)").Groups[1].Value;
```